# Science fiction short story about falling asleep while driving and waking up under a different sky

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story in English online (after the year 2000), that may have been self-published on a website or blog, about a person who is driving through a deserted landscape (possibly an actual desert in the American Southwest) and falls asleep at the wheel.  I think this person was implied to be a white male adult, but I'm not 100% certain.  When they wake up, the sky has changed--possibly there is no moon, and the stars are different?

They meet a bunch of other people who have experienced the same thing and are trapped in this place--they fill the driver in on their grim reality, which involves running out of fuel and avoiding other drivers gone crazy (who have turned to cannibalism?).  The driver eventually gets back in their car and resolves to try to drive out, and falls asleep again...which turns out to be the only way to escape, back to the normal world.  The overall tone was dark and the description of the setting was very evocative.

Does anybody remember the title and/or author of this story, or where I could search for it?  (This is unlikely to be any story by a famous author, or anything written earlier than the 21st century--I think I remember reading comments by online community members at the end of the story, and possibly the author interacting with them.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall in roughly which year (or range of years) you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.